# NetScaler prioritizing faster hosts in round robin

Tags: load-balancing, round-robin, netscaler

For a NetScaler load balancer running SSL passthrough, is there any aspect to the round robin load balancing algorithm that would direct more traffic to hosts that respond more quickly?

As a concrete example, in a load balancer directing traffic to five hosts, four were responding in 2,000ms on average, while one was failing fast and responding within 3ms.

The host that was failing fast received about 99.9% of requests. My understanding is that with round robin, the host should have only received 1/5 of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

As long as they are up, they receive their fair share.

Maybe your service monitors marked the other servers as down because they were so slow to respond? In that case you'd have only one server left that is considered "up". And this would explain the observed behaviour.